# how better to run integration test on Dapr web API project?

Tags: c#, dapr

How I can run integration tests using Dapr? it is possible to run WebApplicationFactory on Web API Dapr project? I see many errors when I run it, and unfortunately all is relate to Dapr create services.

Maybe I can mock it somehow or create stub for Dapr?

I tried to use docker-compose, but I have to much services, maybe I can avoid using docker-compose on tests, if I need only integration tests.

Comment: You mention you're getting errors, could you show us some of them?

Comment: random errors, usually it is timeout on build dapr instance, but I did nothing to run Dapr on my tests. Currently I just use TestContainers to create integration tests using localstack + another integration services, and do not want to use docker-compose to run tests - seems it is unnecessary. But I think that Dapr is very bad designed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, by using the [in-memory testing approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) made possible in asp.net core MVC

Comment: no the question is not to use in-memory or something else, I want to mock somehow Dapr, or emulate it, because on DI it just crashed when you tried to create Dapr instance. As I understood Dapr use 3500 tcp port for http connection on build agent and 50001 for the GRPC https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/integrations/grpc-integration/

Comment: Also when I used the WebApplicationFactory approach I can only replace services on DI, but I can't provide custom startup file like before, when the code is not working on test env just to replace startup with custom implementation, because it can depended on environment.

Comment: From what I know, Dapr has some persistence APIs exposed. You can either mock the abstraction they use in the client libraries, or provide a service implementation (for the sidecar) that uses a test database. Those sidecars are written in golang so I would stick to mocking the client interfaces.

Comment: I personally wouldn't ever use Dapr. I think raw kubernetes (without service mesh) gets you as far as you need to go. EntityFramework for example has an in-memory storage which is sutiable for fast integration tests. Cheers!

Comment: yep, it is, but is not my decision.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still interested with the answer: it's possible with WebApplicationFactory.

The caveat is that you need to start a real kestrel server, because the in-memory one cannot communicate with Dapr.

I managed to write integration tests for Dapr enabled application (also using SQL Server) with TestContainers.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Łukasz Sypniewski said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77588231/15182124), it's possible with WebApplicationFactory.

> The caveat is that you need to start a real kestrel server, because the in-memory one cannot communicate with Dapr.

If anyone is interested in how this is accomplished, check [blog post from Daniel Donbavand](https://danieldonbavand.com/2022/06/13/using-playwright-with-the-webapplicationfactory-to-test-a-blazor-application/). The post is about using playwright with WebApplicationFactory but it explains well how you can run application with WAF on Kestrel. I managed to use this as basis to run integration tests for Dapr-enabled application.